# jqGrid 5.1.0 linked select dropdown inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Fairly new to jqGrid, still learning a lot. Can't get my head around this problem:

I have one 'select' dropdown field where user selects from a range of categories / names, based on user selection I need to populate the next 'select' dropdown with corresponding set of sub categories.

I load my initial list using dataUrl and the sub-categories need to be loaded from dataUrl too.

My code so far:

```
$(function () {
var lastsel2
$("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").jqGrid({
    regional: 'en',
    prmNames: { id: "empTbID" },
    url: "/Budget/GetBdgtEmp",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['EmpTbID', 'DepartmentId', 'DepartmentName', 'EmployeeName', 'EmployeeJobFunctionId', 'EmployeeJobFunctionName', 'EmpStart', 'EmpEnd', 'BsBasic', 'BsPayRise', 'BsComm', 'BsOverTime',
    'BsMthBonus', 'BsQtrBonus', 'BsGross', 'RatesEmpNhi', 'RatesPension', 'BoEmpNhi', 'BoPension', 'BoHealth', 'BoBenefits', 'BoTotal', 'CarStatus', 'CarWDown', 'CarFuel', 'CarRunCost', 'CarTotal',
    'PayRisePercent', 'PayRiseStart'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, name: 'empTbID', index: 'empTbID', editable: false, editoptions: { "class": "jqgrid-readonlycolumn" } },
        { key: false, name: 'departmentId', index: 'departmentId', editable: true },

        {
            key: false,
            name: 'departmentName',
            index: 'departmentName', 
            editable: true,
            edittype: 'select',
            editoptions:
                {
                    size: 1,
                    dataUrl: '/Budget/GetDepartmentListSel'
                }
        },

        { key: false, name: 'employeeName', index: 'employeeName', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'employeeJobFunctionId', index: 'employeeJobFunctionId', editable: true },

        {
            key: false,
            name: 'employeeJobFunctionName',
            index: 'employeeJobFunctionName',
            editable: true
        },

        { key: false, name: 'empStart', index: 'empStart', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'empEnd', index: 'empEnd', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsBasic', index: 'bsBasic', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsPayRise', index: 'bsPayRise', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsComm', index: 'bsComm', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsOverTime', index: 'bsOverTime', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsMthBonus', index: 'bsMthBonus', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsQtrBonus', index: 'bsQtrBonus', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'bsGross', index: 'bsGross', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'ratesEmpNhi', index: 'ratesEmpNhi', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'ratesPension', index: 'ratesPension', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'boEmpNhi', index: 'boEmpNhi', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'boPension', index: 'boPension', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'boHealth', index: 'boHealth', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'boBenefits', index: 'boBenefits', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'boTotal', index: 'boTotal', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'carStatus', index: 'carStatus', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'carWDown', index: 'carWDown', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'carFuel', index: 'carFuel', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'carRunCost', index: 'carRunCost', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'carTotal', index: 'carTotal', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'payRisePercent', index: 'payRisePercent', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'payRiseStart', index: 'payRiseStart', editable: true }],
    onSelectRow: function (empTbID) {
        if (empTbID && empTbID !== lastsel2) {
            $("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").restoreRow(lastsel2);
            $("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").editRow(empTbID, true, '', '', '', '', reload);
            lastsel2 = empTbID;
        }
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter : true,
    editurl: '/Budget/EditBdgtEmp',
    pager: jQuery('#jqControlls_BdgtEmp'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Employees',
    emptyrecords: 'No employees to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: false,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    forceFit:false,
    multiselect: false,
    loadComplete: function () {
        // footer data
        $(this).jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
            empTbID: "<b>Total:</b>",
            bsBasic: $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'bsBasic', false, 'sum'),
            bsPayRise: $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'bsPayRise', false, 'sum'),
            bsComm: $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'bsComm', false, 'sum')
        });
    }
}).navGrid('#jqControlls_BdgtEmp', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Budget/EditBdgtEmp',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Budget/CreateBdgtEmp",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Budget/DeleteBdgtEmp",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this row? ",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    });

$("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: false,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: 'empTbID', numberOfColumns: 12, titleText: '<b>Top level placeholder</b>' }
    ]
});

$("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: false,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: 'empTbID', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<b>Mid placeholder 1</b>' },
        { startColumnName: 'departmentName', numberOfColumns: 6, titleText: '<b>Mid placeholder 2</b>' }
    ]
});

function reload(empTbID, result) {
    $("#jqGrid_BdgtEmp").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
});
```

So in my example above, when user selects the department I need to then load a relevant list of Job Function descriptions based on that initial selection.

Secondary question;

Can you link more than two select fields in a row, as in 'Select 1' (leads to) -> Specific options in 'Select 2' (leads to) -> Specific options in 'Select 3' and so on?

**Research and what I tried so far**

[dialogs_dependent_dropdowns](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/dialogs_dependent_dropdowns/index.html)

[dialogs_dependent_dropdowns 2](http://www.trirand.net/demo/javascript/jqgrid/edit_add_delete/dialogs_dependent_dropdowns/index.html)

[Documentation - see comments](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions)

**EDIT #2**

This is somewhat what I need, albeit done in handsontable: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsvakoLa/)

Taken from this discussion: [GitHub](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1066)

Comment: The first link you posted is exactly  what you need. Can you please post what you try to do, so that we can see the problem you have, since there is no code for this.

Comment: Hi Tony, yes I know but i was unable to follow it - the way I get the data through dataUrl. Also would I have to structure my data as it is in that example too? I was hoping I could juts have different dataUrls depending on the initial selection.

Comment: Think of the second depended drop down as dataUrl, called not directly, but when the edit form is shown. As you can see a ajax is made and and your structure of data can be any  - it is need only when the second select data is delivered to be transformed to a valid select option

Comment: I will give it a go. Its just that I do not understand the code in the example fully - I just keep getting errors. I will post an edit once I get somewhere hopefully

Comment: Can we chat. I have invited